# CreateEnterpriseGeodatabase Oracle Error

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, oracle-spatial

[image][image]

> Executing: CreateEnterpriseGeodatabase Oracle \localhost\orcl #
>   DATABASE_AUTH sys ***** SDE_SCHEMA sde ***** #
>   C:\Users\Med\Desktop\ags103.ecp Start Time: Wed Sep 21 09:45:00 2016
>   User does not have required privileges to create database objects.
>   [ERROR: Must be connected to a 64-bit database to create geodatabase.
>   ] Failed to execute (CreateEnterpriseGeodatabase).

When I try to create enterprise geodatabase I get this error..

Comment: Do you have the database permissions to create new tables etc.?  Are you connected to a 64bit database?

Comment: Yes, i have the 32bit version of oracle and 64bit version of oracle client

Comment: The error message says "Must be connected to a 64-bit database to create geodatabase" yet you say that you are running 32bit Oracle.

Comment: Confirm the @Midavalo comment. Here is the link to the documentation: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/get-started/system-requirements/database-requirements-oracle.htm

Comment: you need to have oracle version matching with your windows and client of that version.

Comment: Please pay attention to the supported platform list. Enterprise geodatabase support has required 64-bit databases since ArcGIS 10.1. In the future please remember  to specify the exact version of all software in your problem description  (for Oracle this is *five* digits, e.g. "Oracle 11.2.0.4.6")

Comment: i'm having the same problem, in summary a 64-bit client should be installed even though I'm with the arcCatalog which is 32 bits? Because I have the 32-bit oracle 11g installed and the 32-bit client also and I get an error that I must connect to a 64-bit database.

Answer (score 1):

The RDBMS hosting an enterprise geodatabase has been required to be a 64-bit application since the release of ArcGIS 10.1.  This is enforced because the SDE.ST_GEOMETRY type is implemented by a DLL extension to the database itself, and DLLs can only be 32-bit *or* 64-bit. The error message that you received stated this fact; there is no work-around possible.

Esri made the decision to restrict new server installation to only 64-bit for a number of reasons, including:

1. New computers had been exclusively 64-bit for a long time
2. The available RAM and memory use characteristics of database servers was quickly changing to eliminate the effectiveness of existing 32-bit servers
3. The potential for expanding into new DBMS engines (both SQL and no-SQL) was being hampered by the need to support many older databases in both 64-bit and (lightly-used) 32-bit flavors -- Moving to exclusive 64-bit support effectively doubled the number of databases which could be supported!

The location of the System Requirements page moved between 10.2 and 10.3, so you now need to do a bit of searching on "ArcGIS server system requirements", but you will quickly find a page similar to [this 10.3.x page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/database-requirements-oracle.htm), which lists:

> Oracle 10g R2 (64 bit) 10.2.0.3 | ...
>
> Oracle 11g R2 (64 bit) 11.2.0.3 | ...
>
> Oracle 12c R1 (64 bit) 12.1.0.1 | ...

as the supported Oracle servers.  Note that [the 10.4.x page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/database-requirements-oracle.htm) only lists:

> Oracle 11g R2 (64 bit) 11.2.0.**4** | ...
>
> Oracle 12c R1 (64 bit) 12.1.0.**2** | ...

(emphasis mine); if you're this late in getting started with 64-bit databases, you'll probably want to make sure you have a clear upgrade path.

Answer (score 0):

As Midavalo, lele3p and Vince already mentioned the Oracle database software has to be 64 bit. The use of 32 bit databse is obviously not only ‘not supported’ it seems to be explicit excluded.

At the client side, assuming you are trying to create the geodatabase by using ArcCatalog please remember that ArcCatalog is a 32 bit application. So you need the corresponding 32 bit Oracle client independent if your database is 64 bit. When you are using the 64 bit Background Geoprocessing you’ll need the 64 bit Oracle client instead. [Geoprocessing background 64 bit](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/64bit-background.htm)

Comment: This is not an answer to a question about 32-bit server use.

Comment: @Vince: This is not correct! For the client (assumed it is ArcCatalog that has the problem in the above question) it is not important if your Oracle database (server) software is 32 bit or 64 bit. That’s why the answer is valid for 32 bit server as well as for 64 bit ones. Beside, I’m at you point of view that one should pay attention to the ESRI specifications. But the main fact is, if you are using the oracle client out of a 32 bit application like ArcCatalog the Oracle client MUST be 32 bit, too.

Comment: The *question* reported an error that could only be generated if 1) The client was *correctly* configured, and 2) The server was at an *unsupported  application word size*. While what you wrote about configuring  clients was mostly true (it ignores the requirements of 64-bit Background Geoprocessing), it doesn't *answer the question*.

Comment: @Vince: Thanks for the hints and corrections. I was too focused on Mohameds comment using a 64 bit Oracle client. Furthermore I thought 32 bit databases are only ‘not supported’ and I was not aware that 32 databases are explicit excluded. I’ve updated my answer and sum up all the insights to the answer that we don’t get anouther question which is answered in a comment as discussed at meta GIS SE: [link]( http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4117/improving-on-almost-19-000-unanswered-questions)